# syntax error near unexpected token `echo'

Tags: linux, shell

I am a **newbie** to stack overflow so please bear with the formatting
It is a genuine problem

I am creating a program to copy ,remove and move a file but still cannot resolve the echo error that bugs it, what should i do?
I have read the other related question which tells to include a ; but this too has not resolved the situation

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Menu "
    echo "1. Copy a File "
    echo "2. Remove a file "
    echo "3. Move a file"
    echo "4. Quit"
    echo "Enter ur Choice \c"
    read Choice
    case " $Choice " in 
    1. echo "Enter File name to copy \c" 
           read f1
       echo " Enter File name \c "  
      read f2         
      if [ -f $f1 ]
      then
      cp $f1 $f2
          else
                 echo "$f1 does not exist"
          fi
          ;;
      2. echo "Enter the File to be removed "
         read r1
         if [ -f $r1 ]
         then      
         rm -i $r1
         else 
              echo "$r1 file does not exist "
         fi
         ;;
      3.
         echo "Enter File name to move \c"
         read f1
         echo "Enter destination \c "
         read f2
         if [ -f $f1 ]
         then 
             if [ -d $f2 ]
             then
                  mv $f1 $f2
             fi
         else
         echo "$f1 does not exist"
         fi
         ;;
     4. 
         echo "Exit......."
         exit;;
         esac
```

**ERRORS**

```
    ./script13.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
    ./script13.sh: line 10: `       1. echo "Enter File name to copy \c " '
    root@Kalilinux1:~/bin#
```

Answer (score 0):

You lack the *parenthesis*, so :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Menu "
echo "1. Copy a File "
echo "2. Remove a file "
echo "3. Move a file"
echo "4. Quit"
read -p "Enter ur Choice >>> "
case " $Choice " in  
    1) echo "Enter File name to copy \c" 
        read f1 
        echo " Enter File name \c "  
        read f2
        if [ -f $f1 ]
        then
            cp $f1 $f2
        else
            echo "$f1 does not exist"
        fi
        ;;
    2) echo "Enter the File to be removed "
        read r1
        if [ -f $r1 ]
        then 
            rm -i $r1
        else 
            echo "$r1 file does not exist "
        fi
        ;;
    3)
        echo "Enter File name to move \c"
        read f1
        echo "Enter destination \c "
        read f2
        if [ -f $f1 ]
        then 
            if [ -d $f2 ]
            then
                mv $f1 $f2
            fi
        else
            echo "$f1 does not exist"
        fi
        ;;
    4) 
        echo "Exit......."
        exit;;
esac
```

Comment: Changes were made and i can execute it now. Thank you!!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer fit your needs. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `1.` in line 10, you should use `1)`. The correct way to do a case statement is:

```
case "$Choice" in 
  1) ...
     ;;
  2) ...
     ;;
```

Also, remove the spaces in `" $Choice "`.